# Paypal Express - no terms and conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

When using paypal express to pay, there is no checkbox to agree to terms and conditions on the review page. Instead, the user is met with a 'Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order'-error.

I have check both /template/paypal/express/review.phtml and paypal.xml-file, and the agreements box seems to be registered in both places.

Any ideas?